# Webpack. Ошибка вовремя загрузки изображения

Tags: изображения, webpack, url, background-image

Изучаю Webpack и столкнулся с проблемой добавления картинки с помощью bg-img в css. При этом, если загружаю картинку в js с помощью import, то при дальнейшем выводе ее в консоль - она открывается. В dist эта картинка, которую хочу добавить с помощью url() в css вовсе не открывается. VS предлагает открыть файл использую текстовый редактор.

Внизу прикрепил пару скринов.

- путь к картинке указывал с помощью автодополнения
- Когда удаляю из правил file-loader, то изображение отображается, При возвращении file-loader - в dist создаётся 2 файла для одного и того же изображения.

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
      context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      mode: 'development',
      entry: {
        main: './index.js',
        analytics: './analytics.js',
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './index.html',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      ],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
            use: ['file-loader'],
          },
        ]
      }
    }
```

Project structure:

[image: Project structure]

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url('../assets/images/webpack-logo.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Result img:

[image: Result img]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
    type: 'asset/resource',
},
```

Вместо:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
    use: ['file-loader'],
},
```